# Stabilizer of action of $GL(N, \mathbb{R}) \times GL(N, \mathbb{R}) $ on $Mat_N (\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-actions

There is a group action $$GL(N, \mathbb{R}) \times GL(N, \mathbb{R}) \times Mat_N (\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow Mat_N (\mathbb{R})$$
$$(A, B, X) \mapsto AXB^{-1} $$

I would like to find stabilizers for this action. I was able to find the orbits of action $$GX = \left\lbrace Y \in Mat_N (\mathbb{R}): rk(Y) = rk(X) \right\rbrace$$

In order to find stabilizers, we must find all solutions of equation $$AXB^{-1} = X$$ for A, B. I know that stabilizer is Lie group and Lie algebra for this stabilizer is $$\mathfrak{g}_X = \left\lbrace (A, B) \in Mat_N (\mathbb{R}) \times Mat_N (\mathbb{R}) : AX - XB = 0 \right\rbrace$$
My question is whether we can more accurately indicate the stabilizer $G_X$?

Thank you so much

Comment: Since you already know the orbits, its enough to compute the stabilizer for one point in each orbit.  This is because if $(A,B) X= Y$, then $Stab_X = (A,B)^{-1} Stab_Y (A,B)$ (or I have the inverse on the wrong one - I didn't think too hard about it).  In any event, you can figure out the stabilizer of the action on the rank one matrices by computing it on $diag(1,0,0,...0)$, and the stabilizer on the rank two matrices by computing it on $diag(1,1,0,..,0)$, etc.

Comment: @Jason DeVito, yes, Thank you so much but maybe there is a beautiful solution?

Comment: What you've defined is technically not a group action, but $(A,B)X:=AXB^{-1}$ is.